# In which file are compiler flags saved by xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-flags

In which file are compiler flags saved by xcode? I can't find the file in which they are saved. I added a flag to multiple files without keeping a track of them. Now I am doing a diff from the previous version to find out which files got changed due to the addition of flags, but there are 0 differences.

Comment: In the .xcodeproj directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler flags together with all other build settings could be in either or both of the following locations:

1. The `pbxproj` file inside the `xcodeproj` container file (that's the default)
2. Separate `xcconfig` files that encapsulate your build settings.

The latter one you need to create and setup manually but is definitely worth the effort.

[Unofficial Guide to xcconfig files](https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/xcconfig_guide.html)